# How to check the user's verification code?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am very new to Spring Boot. This is what I want to do: The user's email is `test@example.com`. That user already exists in my database, but I would like to know if their `verificationCode` is `123`.

**Entity:**

```
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String verificationCode;
    @Column(name = "verified", columnDefinition = "default false")
    private boolean verified = false;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date registrationDate;

    protected Users() {}

    public Users(String email, String password, String verificationCode) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getVerificationCode() {
        return verificationCode;
    }

    public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    }

    public boolean isVerified() {
        return verified;
    }

    public void setVerified(boolean verified) {
        this.verified = verified;
    }
}
```

So with `userRepository.findByEmail("test@example.com")` I am getting the correct user, but how do I check their verification code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using userRepository.findByEmail("test@example.com"), just take the verification code from entity.

```
private static final String CODE = "123";

    final User user = userRepository.findByEmail("test@example.com");
    if (CODE.equals(user.getVerificationCode())) {
    // do something
    }
```

Another option to have it within query.

```
userRepository.findByEmailAndVerificationCode("test@example.com", CODE);
```

Or you can have something similar as Philipp wrote, but I would not get whole entity just find out if it exist. So solution would be

```
if (userRepository.existsByCode(CODE)) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the first option. But I get the error _Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.List<com.example.restapi.entity.Users>', required: 'com.example.restapi.entity.Users'_ ... instead, I have tried it with `final List<Users> user = ...` but then I get the error _Cannot resolve method 'getVerificationCode' in 'List'_

Comment: That means you have more users in database with same email. Is it correct? If you would have one user, it would work. If you have more with same email, then you will get the List. Then depends what you want to do? Check if all users with this mail has the code? Then you have to iterate the list. What Java are you using? If Java 8 and higher, then use users.forEach(u -> { if (CODE.equals(u.getVerificationCode()) { //do something  } });

Comment: No, there is only 1 user with that email in my database.

Comment: If you have one user with email, you cannot get more records and spring would not return list. userRepository.findByEmail("test@example.com") will create similir query to select * from users u where u.email = 'test@example.com'. This query can return more records only if you have more users with the mail.

Comment: Thank you. This is how I tried it and it works fine: `final List<Users> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email); return user.stream().anyMatch(u -> code.equals(u.getVerificationCode()));`

Answer (score 0):

You search for something like that:

```
public void checkVerificationCode(final String verificationCode) {
 final User user = userRepository.findByEmail("test@example.com");

 if (!user.getVerificationCode(verificationCode)) {
  throw new VerificationCodeException("Incorrect verification code.");
 }
}
```

Comment: I get the error _Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.List<com.example.restapi.entity.Users>', required: 'com.example.restapi.entity.Users'_ ... instead, I have tried it with `final List<Users> user = ...` but then I get the error _Cannot resolve method 'getVerificationCode' in 'List'_